Masking Data of type Date doesn't work with Debezium SQL Server Source Connector
I'm trying to mask the "c_birthday" column in table "staff" with data type 'DATE' and "quantity" column of type 'BIGINT' in table "orders" of SQL Server. When checking the message in Kafka topics, I found neither "c_birthday" nor "quantity" are masked. Did I miss something ?
I tried to mask the "c_name" in "staff" with type nvarchar and it worked but for other types, Debezium do nothing. I did check the topic schema in Schema Registry and the result is all 3 of them were masked. But the messages in Kafka topics demonstrated quite opposite, none of the columns defined were masked but for "c_name"
Here's my configurations:
{
    "name": "customer-adhoc-5",
    "config": {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "topic.prefix" : "CDC",
        "database.hostname" : "sqlserver",
        "database.port" : "*****",
        "database.user" : "*****",
        "database.password" : "*****",
        "database.names" : "testDB",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "database.encrypt": "false",
    "table.include.list": "dbo.orders,dbo.staff",
        "column.mask.with.3.chars": "testDB.dbo.orders.quantity,testDB.dbo.staff.c_birthday,testDB.dbo.staff.c_name",
        "schema.history.internal.store.only.captured.tables.ddl": "true",
        "schema.history.internal.store.only.captured.databases.ddl": "true",
        "incremental.snapshot.allow.schema.changes" : "true" ,
        "schema.name.adjustment.mode": "avro",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "****",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "****"
    }
}


The documentation for column.mask.with.length.chars states "The fully-qualified name of a column observes the following format: schemaName.tableName.columnName."  Try dropping the database qualifier "TestDB.".

I did but still, nothing changes

I am out of my area of expertise, but I can suggest a few shots in the dark.  If "dbo.orders.quantity,dbo.staff.c_birthday" does not work try some regular expressions like ".*orders.quantity,.*staff.c_birthday", or ".*quantity.*,.*c_birthday.*", or even ".*" (match all) to see if you can get anything to match. If any of those work, you can experiment with the pattern to get something that works while not yielding unwanted matches.

I tried to use regular expressions like you said but still, other fields were unable to mask.

I started a bounty, to attract attention so that maybe someone more knowledgeable in  Debezium than I (that covers almost anyone) might drop by and offer a solution.

Beyond that, I suggest you take a step back and consider that perhaps it is not these settings which are the problem, but something else that is preventing these settings from being applied. Maybe your control/datatype combination is not supported. Maybe you are looking at the wrong config. Maybe there is a syntax error in the config or elsewhere that is causing these settings to be quietly ignored. Try changing some other config setting that you know to be working to see if it has the expected effect.

Thanks, T N, I'll keep researching for some workaround.
